# Creating an R function that tells you how many coins of a certain cryptocurrency equals to another cryptocurrency?

Tags: r, function, cryptocurrency

I am trying hard to finish my assignment on r language. I am a newbie in computer language, so pardon my ignorance.

I have a dataset with 500 cryptocurrencies and relative data about them. The name of the cryptocurrency is under the column ID, and the value in EUR of one cryptocurrency is under the column current_price. I need to create a new function to convert between cryptocurrencies, with three inputs: the currency I am converting from, the amount of coins I have in that currency, and the currency I am converting to.

This is what I came up with, it does not work, and every time I change it I get a new error.

```
convert <- function (x,amount,z) {
      currency_price <- mdata$current_price
      currency_id <- mdata$id
  index_currency_id_x <- which( x == currency_id) [[1]]
 index_currency_id_z <- which ( z == currency_id) [[1]]
    conversion <- currency_price[[index_currency_id_z]] * amount 
    return (conversion/currency_price[[index_currency_id_z]])
    }
```

If I run every line of code I receive the errors:

```
Error in which(x == currency_id) : object 'x' not found
Error in which(z == currency_id) : object 'z' not found
Error in currency_price[[index_currency_id_z]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index
Error in currency_price[[index_currency_id_z]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

This error just means you haven't supplied x and y to the function. It should be `convert(x=,amount=,y=)`